# DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector()) Portname is empty

Tags: vb.net, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to get the Portname of some working USB-to-Serial adapters connected to a Windows IoT RPi unit. I am still able to open and I am getting an instantiated serialDevice that works. I am able to send and receive data on the port but the PortName object is showing "" so I have no idea if its COM1 or COM2 etc. This would not be a problem except that I am connecting multiple adapters and need a way to identify the adapter uniquely. Anyone else seeing this?

The code I am using to query and open the ports is:

```
 Dim dis = Await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector())
 Dim Count As Integer = 0
    Do Until Count = dis.Count
        Debug.WriteLine("UART Port: " & dis(Count).Name & ", " & dis(Count).Id)
        If dis(Count).Id.Contains("FTDI") Or dis(Count).Id.Contains("FT232") Then
            serialPort = Await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(dis(Count).Id)
        End If
        Count += 1
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a valid `SerialDevice.PortName` on Desktop but not on Windows IoT Core device. Assigning a COM number to a serial device need system-supplied function driver like [Serial.sys etc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff547451(v=vs.85).aspx). But these drivers not provided on Windows IoT Core device. You can check it under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` path.

To identify multiple devices, there is a workaround that using **VID**(vendor ID) and **PID**(product ID). They are considered unique.

So instead of `SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector()` you can use `SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromUsbVidPid(vid, pid)`. You can find VID and PID in `DeviceInformation.Id`. It will like this:

`\\?\USB#VID_10C4&PID_EA60#0001#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}`

Comment: Thanks! I was already using that but was checking to see if there was a reason of if I was missing something as the end user is used to seeing ports labeled COM1, 2, etc. I believe I will most likely create some type of name mappings for use on the companion app for the end users.